# \section, subsection title between table

Tags: tables, sectioning

I use `\section`, `\subsection` on my doc.
I insert `\section` (and `\subsection`) before this command

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}} 
            \toprule
```

that create a table.
I have the same block for 3 table. What I obtain are:
two table, then the name of section and sub section and, at last, the third table.
Why do the name of section and subsection are in the middle of the tabs?

Comment: ok, but what I don't want is that index is inserted between them.

Comment: How can I avoid that?